# How to find cubic $f(x)$ if its remainders are $2x-1$ and $3x-3$ when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^2+x-2$ and $x^2+x-3$, respectively?

Tags: polynomials

How to find cubic $f(x)$ if its remainders are $2x-1$ and $3x-3$ when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^2+x-2$ and $x^2+x-3$, respectively?

My effort is as follows but it looks too complicated. Is there any simpler method?

Let $ax+b$ and $cx+d$ are its quotients so we have

\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x^2+x-2)(ax+b)+2x-1\\
f(x) &= (x^2+x-3)(cx+d)+3x-3
\end{align}

By taking $x=-1$, $x=0$, $x=1$ and $x=2$ we will have 4 equations in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. $f(x)$ can then be determined by finding either a pair of $a$ and $b$ or a pair of $c$ and $d$.

Comment: I can think of other ways to do it, but they still reduce to solving four linear equations in four unknowns, so I wouldn't call anything "simpler".

Comment: In general there will not be such a cubic. If there really is, life is pretty simple. For $a=c$ and $-2b-1=-3d-3$ and there are other equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a *much* simpler method (it boils down to subtracting two linear polynomials)

$$\begin{eqnarray}{\rm mod}\,\ \color{#0a0}{x^2\!+\!x\!-\!3}\!:\ \ f &=& 2x\!-\!1 + (ax\!+\!b)\,(\overbrace{\color{#0a0}{x^2\!+\!x\!-\!3}}^{\large \equiv\ 0\ }\color{#c00}{+1})\\ &\equiv& 2x\!-\!1 + (ax\!+\!b)\,\color{#c00}{(1)}\\ &\equiv& 3x\!-\!3\\
\Rightarrow\ \ ax\!+\!b &\,\equiv\,& 3x\!-\!3 - (2x\!-\!1)\,\equiv\, x\!-\!2\\
\Rightarrow\ \ f &=& x^3\!-x^2\!-2x+3\quad\ {\bf QED}
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

---

If polynomial modular arithmetic is unfamiliar then you may proceed as follows

$$\begin{eqnarray} f &\,=\,& 2x\!-\!1 + (ax\!+\!b)\,(1\color{#c00}{-3\!+\!x\!+\!x^3})\\
&=& 2x\!-\!1 +  ax\!+\!b + (ax\!+\!b)\,(\color{#c00}{-3\!+\!x\!+\!x^3})\end{eqnarray}$$

When divided by $\,\color{#c00}{-3\!+\!x\!+\!x^3}\,$ the above leaves remainder $\,2x\!-\!1 +  ax\!+\!b,\,$ which $\,= 3x\!-\!3\, $ by hypothesis. Therefore, subtracting, we  deduce that $\ ax+b\, =\, 3x\!-\!3-(2x\!-\!1)\, =\, x\!-\!2.$

Comment: @Weirdstress I appended a version without modular arithmetic.

Comment: It is simpler for this particular problem. In general case, we need to perform an additional division operation to find the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that the resultant equations obtained may contain some similar equations, which may leave a wrong impression that there can be infinitely many solutions.

Instead solve it this way. Comparing the coefficients of both the polynomials we get 4 equations, since the degree of each polynomial is $3$. We now have 4 equations and 4 unknowns, solve it for $a,b,c,d$. You will have a unique solution with :

$a=c=1,b=d=-2$

The final answer you will get is:

$$x^3 - x^2-2x+3$$

Comment: It can be done much simpler than solving $4$ equations in $4$ unknowns - see my answer.