# Is there any advantage to the $a \equiv b\;\;(\mathrm{mod}\;c)$ notation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, notation

Congruences modulo equivalence classes other than those defined by division remainders are ubiquitous in contemporary mathematics.  It is not uncommon for a single mathematical argument to refer to multiple equivalence relationships, using ad hoc (but quite clear) notations, such as $\equiv_0$, $\equiv_1$, $\equiv_f$, $\sim_f$, etc.

In light of this (by now well-established) practice, it seems to me a bit strange that Gauss's $a \equiv b\;\;(\mathrm{mod}\;c)$ notation remains in vogue for denoting congruence modulo remainder classes.  Even mathematical-typography-and-notation virtuoso (not to mention author of $\TeX$) Donald Knuth uses it (at least in the book *Concrete Mathematics* that he co-authored).

I'm dumbfounded by this; as mathematical notation goes, $a \equiv b\;\;(\mathrm{mod}\;c)$ (or even its parenthesis-free variant, $a\equiv b\;\;\mathrm{mod}\;c$) strikes me as singularly cumbersome.  It makes me wonder: am I missing something?

Putting aside "extrinsic"<sup>1</sup> considerations such as "conformance to convention", "deference to tradition", "reverence for Gauss", etc., does the $a \equiv b\;\;(\!\!\!\mod{c})$ notation offer any significant benefit over simply $a \equiv_c b$?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is no comment on the merits of these extrinsic reasons.  They are simply not of interest to me in this post.  My aim here is to focus only on the question intrinsic utility as mathematical notation, and especially as *typeset* mathematical notation.</sub>

Comment: $\equiv_c$ has a tiny letter which is hard to read in some cases.  Further, $\equiv_c b$ has potential for confusing with $\equiv cb$ or $\equiv~ _cb$.

Comment: So the three reasons you gave are sort of hyperbolically melodramatic and comical parodies of the real reason, which is that the mod notation is widely recognized. That notation can almost be used without explanation (except where it's being introduced of course.) the subscript notation would definitely have to be explained, because it is definitely more obscure.

Comment: @rschwieb: AFAIC, "widely recognized" is the same as "conformance to convention."  What's hyperbolic/melodramatic about that?  Besides, every obsolete notation was "widely recognized" before it was replaced, so, as *sole* selling point, it strikes me as rather weak.

Comment: @vadim: Your first justification strikes me as weak. But your second justification is just ridiculous! What on earth can ${}_cb$ _mean_ in a number-theoretical context?

Comment: It's also always good to keep in mind that the more concise notation is, the more clarity it loses. There's a balance to be struck.

Comment: The possibility for confusion with $\equiv cb$ is obvious to anybody who likes number theory and doesn't have neat handwriting.  Not all math is done in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @kjo if that is what you think, then it is clear you are ranting and not asking a real question. If you forbid all sorts of answers that you don't want to hear, and then insist on sorting reasonable answers into those categories, so that there is no answer except the one you want, you are not asking a real question.

Comment: @kjo: Your suggestion seems very reasonable to me.

Comment: @TonyK: thanks for your comment!  Bill Dubuque's answer, however, convinced me that the traditional notation is more practical than I'd realized.  (Now I see that my exposure to this notation is limited only to the simplest situations.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few  reasons immediately spring to mind:

$(1)\ \, $ The *scope* of $\!\pmod{\!m}\,$ often encloses more than a single congruence, e.g. including an entire line of congruences $\,a\equiv b\equiv \cdots \equiv c.\,$ Shifting this default context off to the sidelines (start/end of line) removes redundant notation that may obfuscate the essence of the matter.

$(2)\ \, $ Often times the "modulus" is a large expression, so it will not fit comfortably in a subscript on the congruence symbols, e.g. in a [post yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713228/242) I worked $\!\pmod{\! x^2+x-3}$eui

$(3)\ \, $ In more general rings one often works modulo *multiple* elements (i.e. *nonprincipal* ideals), $ $ e.g. $\pmod{n,\  a+b\sqrt{d}},\, $ or $\pmod{n,f(x)}\ $ or $ \pmod{x,\, y^2-x},\,$ which, again, are too big for subscripts, and better absorbed into (global) ambient context notation.

But if one prefers subscripts then one can introduce short names for lengthy congruences or ideals and then use these short names in subscripts.

Comment: OK, I'm convinced.  :)

Comment: I prefer $a \equiv b \pmod{142857}$ to $a \equiv_{142857} b$